# Classifying new instance with bayesian net

Tags: machine-learning, classification, bayesian-networks

Say I have the following bayesian network:

[image]

And I want to classify a new instance on wether H=true or H=false, 
the new instance looks e.g. like this: `Fl=true, A=false, S=true, and Ti=false`.

How can I classify the instance with respect to H?

I can compute the probability by multiplying the probabilities from the tables:

`0.4 * 0.7 * 0.5 * 0.2 = 0.028`

What does this say about whether the new instance is a positive instance H or not?

**EDIT**
I will try the compute the probability according to Bernhard Kausler's suggestion:

So this is Bayes' rule: 
`P(H|S,Ti,Fi,A) = P(H,S,Ti,Fi,A) / P(S,Ti,Fi,A)`

to compute de denominator:
`P(S,Ti,Fi,A) =  P(H=T,S,Ti,Fi,A)+P(H=F,S,Ti,Fi,A) = (0.7 * 0.5 * 0.8 * 0.4 * 0.3) + (0.3 * 0.5 * 0.8 * 0.4 * 0.3) =0.048`

`P(H,S,Ti,Fi,A) = 0.336`

so `P(H|S,Ti,Fi,A) = 0.0336 / 0.048 = 0.7`

now i compute `P(H=false|S,Ti,Fi,A) = P(H=false,S,Ti,Fi,A) / P(S,Ti,Fi,A)`
we already have the value for `P(S,Ti,Fi,A´. I's ´0.048`.

`P(H=false,S,Ti,Fi,A) =0.0144`

so `P(H=false|S,Ti,Fi,A) = 0.0144 / 0.048 = 0.3`

the Probability for `P(H=true,S,Ti,Fi,A)` is the highest. so the new instance will be classified as **H=True**

Is this correct?

**Addition:** We do not need to calculate `P(H=false|S,Ti,Fi,A)` because it is 1 - `P(H=true|S,Ti,Fi,A)`.

Answer (score 1):

So, you want to compute the conditional probability `P(H|S,Ti,Fi,A)`. To do that, you have to use Bayes' rule:

```
P(H|S,Ti,Fi,A) = P(H,S,Ti,Fi,A) / P(S,Ti,Fi,A)
```

where

```
P(S,Ti,Fi,A) = P(H=T,S,Ti,Fi,A)+P(H=F,S,Ti,Fi,A)
```

You then calculate both conditional probabilities P(H=T|S,Ti,Fi,A) and P(H=F|S,Ti,Fi,A) and make a prediction according to which probability is higher.

Just multiplying up the numbers like you did won't help and doesn't even give you a proper probability since the product is not normalized.

Comment: is P(H,S,Ti,Fi,A) computed by multiplaying each probability? -->P(H)*P(S)*... ?

Comment: @user1291235 Yes, but you can of course only compute it for certain instances of the random variables, for example P(H=T,S=T,Ti=T,Fi=T,A=T)=0.7*0.8*0.8*0.4*0.3

Comment: thank you, i tried to solve it, and edited my question, could you take a look at it? :)